# What's the best way to insert values into their "proper" place in a pandas dataframe by some (index) parameter?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, indexing

I have a dataframe, `df`, like so:

```
Word    Row ID  Remark
abc     1       xyz
def     2       xyz
ghi     4       uvw
jkl     5       qrs
mno     7       wxy
```

The missing values are in anotherdataframe, `df1`:

```
Word    Row ID  Remark
pqr     3       uuu
stu     6       vvv
```

I want to insert the missing values in `df1` in their proper place in `df1`, so this is the desired output:

```
Word    Row ID  Remark
abc     1       xyz
def     2       xyz
pqr     3       uuu
ghi     4       uvw
jkl     5       qrs
stu     6       vvv
mno     7       wxy
```

My code to do this is as follows:

```
for i in range(len(df1)):        # run through each of the missing values
    if df2['Row ID'][i] not in range(min(df['Row ID']), df2['Row ID'][i]):
        df.loc[-1] = df2.loc[i]  # adding a row with -1 index
        df.index += 1            # shifting index so that it does not overwrite the current value in that position

df = df.sort_values('Row ID')
```

But this, I think, is not the most efficient way to do it, as:

1. There is a for loop. I think there must be a vectorized way to do it.
2. There is a sort operation at the end of the for loop. I think if there is a vectorized way, it would incorporate the sorting in that step itself, and not do it in a separate step.

Comment: Since you are sorting at the end anyway, just concatenate the frames together and sort: `df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_values('Row ID')`

Comment: @ALollz Oh nice. But this reverses the order of the columns for some reason, and also adds another column `Index` as the first column of the resulting dataframe.

Comment: So is `Word` your index?

Comment: No, I'm just saying its adding another column named `Index` with its value as `NaN` for the rows inserted, and the original index values for the rows already present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `searchsorted`, personally think `concat`+ `sort_values` can solve the problem as well.

```
df1.index=np.searchsorted(df.RowID.values,df1.RowID.values)
pd.concat([df1,df]).sort_index()
Out[187]: 
  Word  RowID Remark
0  abc      1    xyz
1  def      2    xyz
2  pqr      3    uuu
2  ghi      4    uvw
3  jkl      5    qrs
4  stu      6    vvv
4  mno      7    wxy
```

Comment: I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'RowID'`

Comment: @Kristada673 change `df.RowID` to `df['Row ID']`

Comment: @Kristada673 then print you df.columns

Comment: `Index(['Word', 'Row ID', 'Remark'], dtype='object')`

Comment: @Kristada673 `np.searchsorted(df['Row ID']values,df['Row ID'].values)`

Comment: Oh, stupid me, I found the problem. I had put the missing values in a dataframe `df2` with another name for `Row ID`, and was running the code with `df1`. Lol. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: So is there no other more efficient method, other than first reassigning the indices of the missing values, and then concatenating them to the original dataframe? This is still 2 operations; I was kinda hoping for a 1-operation solution.

Comment: @Kristada673 then I think `pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_values('Row ID')` will work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with merging? Given both dataframes have the same structure in terms of number and names of columns. Otherwise you can extract such order from the master dataframe and create a merged one with the values of reference you need:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Word' : [ "pqr","stu"],
                    'rowid' : [ '3','6'],
                   'Remark' : ['uuu', 'vvv']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Word' : ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"],
                    'rowid' : ['1', '2', '4','5', '7'],
                   'Remark' : ['xyz', 'xyz', 'uvw', 'vvv', 'wxy']})
```

And merging:

```
df1['rowid'] = df1['rowid'].astype(int)
df2['rowid'] = df2['rowid'].astype(int)
dfmerg = pd.merge(df2, df1, how = "outer",sort=True)
dfmerg.sort_values('rowid')
```

Which output

```
  Word  rowid Remark
0  abc      1    xyz
1  def      2    xyz
5  pqr      3    uuu
2  ghi      4    uvw
3  jkl      5    vvv
6  stu      6    vvv
4  mno      7    wxy
```

The reason why I like this solution, it releases me from the need of indexing so I can index afterwards based on other criteria.